# Linq2Entites Count() with condition on bool not working as "I thought it would"?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

Given the following very simple linq statement

```
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.Count(g => g.Verified);
```

or

```
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.Count(g => g.Verified == true);
```

where `Verified` is a bool, I get an exception saying this is not supported by linq-2-entities?

Have a missed something very simple - or should I choose one from:

```
a)
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.Where(g => g.Verified).Count();
```

or

```
b)
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.ToList().Count(g => g.Verified);
```

both these work (and my list is only 30-50 long, so ToList isn't a problem).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't missed anything. Count with predicate is not supported by Linq to Entitities. See msdn article [Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738550.aspx)

And yes, you should go with first option, because `ToList()` will execute query and bring all entities into memory:

```
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.Where(g => g.Verified).Count();
```

Even if you don't have many records in your `ReportGroups` table - why would you do something, which is slower, and uses more pc, database and network resources?  Compare transferring one integer value to transferring all fields of 50 `ReportGroup` entities, creating .net objects from `DataReader` (and holding connection opened), and iterating over created list, executing predicate method on each of `DataReader` entities. I think transferring one integer value wins here.

Comment: Won the points because of the link and explanation: In actual fact I need more than one value from the result set - so will see which is faster: Load all records into a List and then run 5 queries against that (which then supports the count predicate where required) or running 5 queries with `Where().Count()` signature.

Answer (score 3):

I would go for first option as *first will not bring all records* for calculating the count. In second option `ToList` method will bring data and apply count on it.

```
vm.VerifiedGroups = db.ReportGroups.Where(g => g.Verified).Count();
```